# error with checking target: expected dense_49 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (2250, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
model=models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(7, activation='relu', input_shape=(50,50,3)))

model.add(layers.Dense(7, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=50,epochs=10, verbose=1)

results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

The above is my python code. Can anyone tell my what am I missing. FYI, I have 2250 images in my training set, each of the shape `(50,50,3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look to the following dense layers Image from [here](https://blog.datawow.io/interns-explain-basic-neural-network-ebc555708c9). 
[image]
Dense layer connects each node in *layer-L* to every node in  *layer-L+1*. Even-though it is not necessarily true, the input to dense layer often have shape (batch_size, width, channels). Keras documentation says: "[If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then it is flattened prior to the initial dot product with  kernel](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense)".
Back to your question. In your case you specified the input shape to be((50,50,3). Now the first dense layer expects inputs with shape(batch_size, 50, 50,3) and produces output with shape [batch_size, 50,50, 7],i.e inputs and outputs have rank 4. The same goes for the last layer with softmax activation. So the output of the last layer will have rank 4, i.e shape (batch_size, 50, 50, 3). For this reason the model is expecting the labels to have this(batch_size, 50, 50, 3) shape.

**Solution**
Use vectors as input to dense layer. Steps to follow.

1. Change the input shape argument

   `model.add(layers.Dense(7, activation='relu', input_shape=(50*50*3,)))`
2. Reshape X_train and X_test to deal with new input_shape

`#assuming X_train and X_test are numpy array`
`X_train  = X_train.reshape(-1,50*50*3)`
`X_test  = X_test.reshape(-1,50*50*3)`